# How can I remove an entry from a list in a shells script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Bash Menu Script Example

PS3='Please enter your choice: '
options=("Option 1" "Option 2" "Option 3" "Quit")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
        "Option 1")
            echo "you chose choice 1"
            ;;
        "Option 2")
            echo "you chose choice 2"
            ;;
        "Option 3")
            echo "you chose choice 3"
            ;;
        "Quit")
            break
            ;;
        *) echo invalid option;;
    esac
done
```

My problem is that I don't know how to remove a choice from the list after it has been selected. Is that possible? How?

Comment: I removed the dash tag since you're using bash, a very different beast. Please clarify what exactly you mean by "removing", do you want to shift all other array entries downwards, or simply leave one of the keys blank? What will you use this for?

Comment: out teacher ask us to create a game where you create for themes using the case statement each theme contains several question after the user selects a theme and answers the question it will prompted to select another theme ,

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16860877/remove-element-from-array-shell/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `unset`:

```
$ options=(aa bb cc dd)
$ echo ${options[@]}
aa bb cc dd
## Remove the 3d element of the array (arrays start at 0)
$ unset options[2]
$ echo ${options[@]}
aa bb dd
```

For more details, see `help unset`:

```
unset: unset [-f] [-v] [name ...]
    Unset values and attributes of shell variables and functions.

    For each NAME, remove the corresponding variable or function.

    Options:
      -f    treat each NAME as a shell function
      -v    treat each NAME as a shell variable

    Without options, unset first tries to unset a variable, and if that fails,
    tries to unset a function.

    Some variables cannot be unset; also see `readonly'.

    Exit Status:
    Returns success unless an invalid option is given or a NAME is read-only.
```

Comment: but how would i know which array was selected

Comment: @user259584 huh? What do you mean? You give the array name. For example `foo=(aa bb cc); unset foo[2]`. In my example  the name of the array is actually `array`. I have edited to avoid confusion.

Comment: after a user chooses lets say Option 1 i don't want it to appear in the menu the next time all i want there is Option 2 Option 3 and Quit @terdon

Comment: @user259584 that's a bit more complex. It depends on how you are re-displaying the menu to the user. Personally I would use a function to do this and pass the `$options` array as a parameter to that function. That way, it will only show the values that are currently in the array.

Comment: can i use the unset statement inside case like this select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
        "function1")
            func1
            unset options[1]

Comment: Probably yes, I don't see why not. Just try and if you encounter more problems, post a new question.